# How to connect Likedin with phonegap

Tags: cordova, oauth

I want to connect Likedin with my app using Phonegap.I have  search for plugins and OAuth procedure,there is no update Regarding that.Does any body Know how to Log In and get Likedin details using Phonegap App.

Comment: Kindly update If you know any plugins

Comment: Does any Body Know javascript API for mobile app in linkedin

Answer (score 3):

As of now linkdin plugin is not available for phonegap but you can manually implement this with Inappbrowser plugin.

I have used angularjs with phonegap as its just awesome javascript framework. Below code will give you some idea.

```
$scope.linkdin = function (title,description,image,index) {
        //window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message only');
        $scope.linkdinUrl = "http://m3.licdn.com/media/p/3/000/124/1a6/089a29a.png";
        $scope.linkdinTilte = title;
        $scope.linkidnSummary = description;
        $scope.linkidnImage =  "http://122.182.14.107:8080/GESmartCatalog/feature/image/"+$scope.fm_data[index].id+".png";
        //alert($scope.linkidnImage)
        if(localStorage.getItem("linkedinWindowExpiry") == '0')
        {
            localStorage.setItem("linkedinWindowValue", "0")
        }

        if(localStorage.getItem("linkedinWindowValue") == '0' && localStorage.getItem("linkedinWindowExpiry") == '0')
        {
            localStorage.setItem("linkedinWindowValue", "1");
            $scope.linkedinWindowText = 'location=no';
        }
        else
        {
            // alert("sfgfsg");
            // alert(localStorage.getItem("linkedinWindowExpiry"));
            $scope.linkedinWindowText = 'location=no';  
        }



        $rootScope.shareXmlLinkedin = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>"+
                                        "<share>"+
                                          "<comment></comment>"+
                                          "<content>"+
                                             "<title>"+$scope.linkdinTilte+"</title>"+
                                            "<description>"+$scope.linkidnSummary+"</description>"+
                                           "<submitted-url>"+$scope.linkdinUrl+"</submitted-url>"+
                                            "<submitted-image-url>"+$scope.linkidnImage+"</submitted-image-url>"+
                                         "</content>"+
                                         "<visibility>"+
                                            "<code>anyone</code>"+
                                          "</visibility>"  +
                                        "</share>";

        var ref = window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=gw80y7867ukx&scope=rw_nus w_messages r_fullprofile&state=zwdkLai5urm0AscP&redirect_uri=http://www.softwebcms.com','_blank',$scope.linkedinWindowText);
            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e){

                if(e.url.indexOf('?code=') >=0 ){
                    if(e.url.match(/=[^]+&/)){
                        var code = e.url.match(/=[^]+&/)[0].substring(1).replace('&','');
                       // alert(code)
                        window.sessionStorage.setItem('code', code);

                        ref.close();

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code='+code+'&redirect_uri=http://www.softwebcms.com&client_id=gw80y7867ukx&client_secret=zwdkLai5urm0AscP',
                            success: function(a){
                                //alert(JSON.stringify(a));
                                    //alert(a.access_token);

                                    localStorage.setItem("linkedinWindowExpiry", a.expires_in);
                                        //alert($rootScope.shareXmlLinkedin);   
                                     $.ajax({
                                            url : 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token='+a.access_token,
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            method : 'POST',
                                            headers : {
                                                'Content-Type'  : 'application/xml'
                                            },
                                            data: $rootScope.shareXmlLinkedin,
                                            success: function(a){

                                                $modal.open({
                                                    template: "<div class='modal-body'><div style='width:100%; text-align:center; '><h3 style='text-align:center;'>Added to Linkedin</h3></div>",
                                                    windowClass: "main_popup_width dialog",
                                                    controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance) {

                                                                setTimeout(function(){$rootScope.wtbfavactive="123";$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel')},3000);

                                                              },
                                                    }); 
                                            },
                                            error: function(a){
                                                console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
                                                //alert(JSON.stringify(a))
                                                $modal.open({
                                                    template: "<div class='modal-body'><div style='width:100%; text-align:center; '><h3 style='text-align:center;'>Already posted to Linkedin</h3></div>",
                                                    windowClass: "main_popup_width dialog",
                                                    controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance) {

                                                                setTimeout(function(){$rootScope.wtbfavactive="123";$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel')},3000);

                                                              },
                                                    }); 
                                            }
                                        })

                            },
                            error: function(a){
                                //alert(JSON.stringify(a))
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
      };
```

Hope this helps...
Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for the update Adarsh.But I dont How to implement this in Phonegap.Can you brief it.Did you implemented Likedin in Phonegap.

Comment: you need to install inappbrowser plugin for this. you need to make two ajax calls inside inappbrowser as shown in above code. after this it will ask user to login. Basically i have implement this for sharing text, link or image to linkedin wall

Comment: I have already installed in app browser.I want to login and get details,not for sharing.One more thing while registering our app in Likedin it asked javascript API domain.What we have to mention over there

Comment: while am trying to login its showing javascript api domain error

Comment: @JothiSankarNKanakavel - please could you update on this? I am trying to implement the same...

Comment: @AdarshNahar - hi Adarsh.. am looking for a similar implementation.. could you please help

Comment: If you have an inappbrowser installed in phonegap then just place above linkedin function and call it from html and it will start working. if you are not using angularjs then use var to define instead of $scope. Let me know if anything required.

Comment: Nice one guy! It works flawlessly using Intel XDK and the InAppBrowser vers. 1.3.1 (converted using plain js). Anyway I used "http://localhost" as redirect_uri.

Answer (score 1):

As of now there are no Plugin available for phonegap. but you can use Javascript API to connect Linkedin accounts. follow this link [Linkedin Javascript API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial)
& [Sign in Tutorial](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin)
You can call this API using inappbrowser plugin. rest you can manage it with the help of javascript and session management. Hope this helps.!

Comment: Hi Deep thanks for the reply.But i want how to specify           JavaScript API Domains: for mobile app(Phonegap).

Comment: you need to call those apis when needed. if you have tried facebook integration in that we call facebook javascript api in the same way first you need to understand the working of the Linkedin api and implement.

Comment: Fine Deep.I also Did Facebook integration but there will be a redirect URL for Facebook,So no problem in that,But we dont have such URL for Likedin.I cant able to Login Using Likedin in my app Using API key.It throwing Error Javascript API Domain.Thats Why i ask you.I have searched lot but no solution still

Comment: DID you implemented Likedin in Phonegap